# concrete5 - jQueryUI in Edit mode

Tags: concrete5

I use carousel plugin that depends on jQueryUI. To have it loaded I simply use [Load jQueryUI addon](http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/load-jquery-ui/) from marketplace.

Edit - To be more exact. What happens is:

A. when `problematic.js` is loaded directly - without any `if`: carousel doesn't work when user is logged in and content of top bar ("Edit", "Dashboard") dissapers, so it is even impossible to go into Edit Mode

B. when `problematic.js` is loaded with such condition:

```
if (!$c->isEditMode()){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="problematic.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

exactly as above: carousel doesn't work when user is logged in and content of top bar ("Edit", "Dashboard") dissapers, so it is even impossible to go into Edit Mode

C. when `problematic.js` is loaded with such condition:

```
<?php $u = new User();
if (!$u->isRegistered()){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="problematic.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

content of top bar is present, it is possible to turn page into Edit Mode but obviously js file is not executed when user is logged in.

However that's not what I need - I want my script to be working when:

1. user is not logged,
2. user is logged into website but page IS NOT in edit mode.

I want script NOT to be executed when page IS in Edit Mode ONLY.

How should I achieve this?

Edit: Here's part of PHP/HTML code:

```
<?php 
    defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_('Access Denied.'));
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php Loader::element('header_required');?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print $this->getThemePath(); ?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print $this->getThemePath(); ?>/js/jquery.ui.rcarousel.min.js"></script>
        <?php $u = new User();
    if (!$u->isRegistered()){ ?>
        <!-- To prevent conflicts with C5 jQuery UI when in edit mode -->           
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print $this->getThemePath(); ?>/js/home.js"></script>
    <?php } ?>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php print $this->getStyleSheet('css/style.css'); ?>" />
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' />
    </head>
    <body <?php  if ($c->isEditMode()) { ?> class='editmode' <?php  } ?>>
        <div class='c5wrapper'>
             <div id='container'>
                 <div id='content-promo' class='content-promo full-width'>
                     <div id='carousel-wrapper' class='content-promo carousel-wrapper'>
                         <?php
                            $a = new Area('Carousel');
                            $a->display($c);
                         ?>
                     </div>  <!-- End of carousel wrapper -->

                     <a href='#' id='ui-carousel-prev' class='carousel-controls'><span class='carousel-control-text'>Prev</span></a>
                     <a href='#' id='ui-carousel-next' class='carousel-controls'><span class='carousel-control-text'>Next</span></a>

                 </div>  <!-- End of content promo -->
<?php $this->inc('elements/footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How does the first code example not work? It doesn't do what you expet? Or it doesn't do anything at all? Assuming that it functionally works (ie, adds that  tag when not in edit mode), then the full solution to what you want to do would be:

```
<?php $u = new User();
if ($u->isRegistered() && ! $c->isEditMode()) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="problematic.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

If the first code example doesn't work, then it's possible $c has been redefined, or something else equally unlikely...

Comment: 1. when first code example is used:
  A. user not logged: carousel works,
  B. user logged but not in Edit Mode - carousel does not work
  C. user logged and in Edit Mode -  carousel does not work
2. apologies, I wasn't specific enough - I want `problematic.js` executed when user is not logged, when user is looged but not in Edit Mode and I don't want it to be executed in Edit Mode ONLY

Comment: I need to change my original question a bit, couple days ago additional effect was disappearing content of top bar when first code example used and user logged in. I have just checked it and now it seems that the only efect is that code from `problematic.js` is not executed when user logged (carousel doesn't work)

Comment: please ignore my second comment - I uploaded wrong file into server and fooled myself, now original question is edited and I hope it is more clear

Comment: Not a lot clearer... :) You need to differentiate between the code "working" (by having the problematic.js script tag being included in the HTML source), and the carousel working or not. It sounds to me like the code that we're discussing is working (ie, including the script tag when you want it to), but the problem is in the actual js file... and that's a whole different question. My first suggestion for that, given what's happening, is that the problematic.js is including jquery (or jquery ui or something), which c5 is already including. Make sure it doesn't do that.

Comment: you're right - there's a difference: in cases A & B - whether user is logged or not - `problematic.js` is included, but carousel doesn't work when user is logged; in case C - `problematic.js` is included only when user is NOT logged, so actually both code examples works as they are supposed and the reason of problem is different... here's my [`problematic.js`](http://jsfiddle.net/VkqmF/)

Comment: I'd bet that there's a javascript error. Have you checked the console?  The source doesn't run on jsfiddle because rcarousel isn't available. Is that getting successfully loaded? The console should help you figure things out from here.... (Also, you really should use css media queries in place of all that crazy `if (width > x)` stuff.

Comment: I use media queries, that "crazy stuff" is required to overwrite default carousel dimensions. Hmm, everything in the script seems to be working: carousel is working, proper names are assigned to "Prev" and "Next" links... I'll try to recode js file and will be back